# App crashes while using AlertDialogs

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have set a list, and when i touch one item of the list, i want the app to generate an AlertDialog. However, when I touch an item, the app crashes and i have now idea why. Here is my Code.

```
DATA = new ArrayList<Student>();
    adapter1 = new StudentAdapter(this, R.layout.studentitemlayout, DATA);
    listview01 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    listview01.setAdapter(adapter1);

    listview01.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "You clicked " + position + " student");
            AlertDialogFragment fragment = new AlertDialogFragment();
            fragment.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState).show();
        }
    });
```

and my class for the Fragment

```
public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "MyStudentsData";

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage("New Lesson!")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG , "YES");
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG , "NO");
                }
            });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}
```

}

AND ONE FINAL QUESTION
why this code fails and gets me a crash on the app?

```
/*newLessonAlertDialog fragment = new newLessonAlertDialog();
            fragment.show(getFragmentManager(),DEBUG_TAG); */
            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).create();
            alert.setTitle("nikos");
            alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call it with `show`. No need to call `onCreateDialog`

```
fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Some tag");
```

Comment: thank you it worked for me but i do not understand why.
when i generate a Fragment how onCreateDialog is called?

Comment: It is done within the fragment. Read the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: @user3596026 what about accepting the answer? It helped you wright?

Answer (score 0):

You are using DialogFragment, so you should call fragment.show() instead of onCreateDialog method.